# Dell Perc5/E and Poweredge 1950 PCI-X

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, dell-perc, pci

Today I have been to my datacenter and could not put Perc5/E into PCI-X card, there is like 0,5mm difference in card length, so physically it does not fit.

Do I need PCIe for this Perc?

Btw. when removed PCI-X, the system did not want to boot due to missing card, both cards have to be installed, is it the same with PCIe? So I have to buy only a pair?

Thanks for your advices :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Per5/E is a PCIe card.  You need the correct slot open to install the card.  I believe the Perc5/i is the PCI-X "equivalent".